# Rabbitmq blocking at new connection creation within storm topology

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-storm

I am new to storm i am using rabbitmq within my spout that recieves tuples from some queue and there is a client running one some other machine that inserts tuples to that queue I ran a simple rabbitmq example program that works fine but when i am using it within storm spout it gest blocked at

```
connection = factory.newConnection();
```

even though my rabbitmq server is also running and on the same machine when i run example code it runs successfully.
print statements print to the statement

```
System.out.println(" setting host to 192.168.8.218..... ");
```

below is my complete spout class.

```
package storm.starter.spout;

import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RabbitmqSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
    public final static String QUEUE_NAME = "record";
    ConnectionFactory factory;
    Connection connection;
    Channel channel;
    QueueingConsumer consumer;

    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) 
    {
        _collector = collector;
        System.out.println(" [*] Intilization of spout..... ");

        try
        {
            factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            System.out.println(" creating connection factory..... ");
            factory.setHost("192.168.8.96");
            System.out.println(" setting host to 192.168.8.218..... ");
            connection = factory.newConnection();
            System.out.println(" creating new connection..... ");
            channel = connection.createChannel();
            System.out.println(" creating new channel..... ");
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            System.out.println(" Declaring queue..... ");
            System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. ");
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred. "+exception.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void nextTuple() 
    {
        System.out.println("In wait of tuples.... ");
        try
        {
            consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
            System.out.println(" trying to consume..... ");
            channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);

            while (true) 
            {
                System.out.println(" trying to deliver..... ");
                QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
                String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
                System.out.println(" getting string..... ");
                System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
                System.out.print("emitting Rabbitmq Queue tuple");
                _collector.emit(new Values(message));
                System.out.print("emitted Rabbitmq Queue tuple");
            }   
        }

        catch(IOException io)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred. ");
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred. ");
        }


    }        

    @Override
    public void ack(Object id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void fail(Object id) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) 
    {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("record"));
    }
```

}

Comment: You might want to try the storm-amqp-spout for connecting to RabbitMQ https://github.com/Xorlev/storm-amqp-spout

Answer (score 0):

```
connection = factory.newConnection()
```

Is done in `RabbitMQConsumer()` method of RabbitMQConsumer class because data is taken out of the queue by RabbitMQ consumer and that in turn gives data to your RabbitMQ spout.
please refer:
[https://github.com/ppat/storm-rabbitmq/tree/master/src/main/java/io/latent/storm/rabbitmq][1]